# Parse HTML Table Cell ID

Tags: html, html-table, html-parsing

I have a table cell ID, for example, that looks like "#emp0-1". The 0 in this example is the x coordinate and the 1 is the y coordinate. What would be the best way to pull only the x and/or y component of this table cell ID? We need them in order to populate the rest of our table we have created.

What we have is a grid to represent a calendar shown in the screenshot here: [image: Screenshot of our Schedular]. The far left column is fixed with employee names and the top column is fixed with dates. We need to be able to insert a task into the table that lines up with the employee's name and spans its duration. The rest of the table is generated based off the number of rows and columns that are fixed at the beginning. Our first idea was to assign an ID to each cell of the table in an x-y coordinate format.

What would be the best idea for identifying every cell?

Thank you for your time!

Comment: will it always be "#emp{X}-{y}"

Comment: can you edit the table? like add class to every cell? if yes, answer is very simple!